# How to unpack enum value used in Flask Sqlaclhemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, enums, flask-sqlalchemy

I have enum defined .

```
from enum import Enum
class Status(Enum):
    pending = 'PENDING'
    processed = 'PROCESSED'
    delivered = 'DELIVERED'
```

In model.py

```
class Activity(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'activity'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True))
    message = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Enum(Status), nullable=False)
```

in controller.py

```
jsn_data = request.get_json()
activity_obj = Activity(message=jsn_data['message'], status=jsn_data['status'])
```

in request json body

```
{
   "message": 'Hi',
   "status':'pending'
}
```

So here i want status value "PENDING" store in DB instead of 'pending'.
Let me know what i am missing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) has an example:

```
import enum
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    one = 1
    two = 2
    three = 3

t = Table(
    'data', MetaData(),
    Column('value', Enum(MyEnum))
)
```

> **Above, the string names of each element, e.g. “one”, “two”, “three”,
>   are persisted to the database;** the values of the Python Enum, here
>   indicated as integers, are not used; the value of each enum can
>   therefore be any kind of Python object whether or not it is
>   persistable.
>
> In order to persist the values and not the names, the
>   `Enum.values_callable` parameter may be used. For a simple enumeration
>   that uses string values, a callable such as
>
> `lambda x: [e.value for e in x]` is sufficient.

So, to use values instead of keys specify `values_callable`:

```
t = Table(
    'data', MetaData(),
    Column('value', Enum(MyEnum, 
     values_callable=lambda x: [str(e.value) for e in MyEnum])
    )
   )
)
```

I would suggest to use `echo=True` with `create_engine` to see what SQL was generated.

Comment: I have gone through the docs but didnt relate with my case , may i didnt understand .i just wanted to know that how to i feed the enum value to db column .

Comment: @VivekKumar I've added more information about the topic.

Comment: it works for me . Thanks a lot . In my case i changed like this ```status = db.Column(db.Enum(Status,values_callable=lambda x: [str(e.value) for e in Status]), nullable=False)```